# how to implement side drawer and stack navigator together

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have two navigation types, stack and drawer navigation. I have implemented both navigation types in different files and have gone through the react-navigation v5 docs to make it work without success.

This is the drawer navigator

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import About from '../screens/about';
import More from '../screens/more';
import Gallery from '../screens/gallery';
import Excos from '../screens/excos';
import AbuladWebsite from '../screens/abuladwebsite';
import LifeInAbu from '../screens/lifeinabu';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function sideStack() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Gallery" component={Gallery} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Life in ABU" component={LifeInAbu} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Buy and Sell" component={AbuladWebsite} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={About} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Excos" component={Excos} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="More" component={More} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default sideStack;
```

This is the stack navigator

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Login from '../login/login';
import Register from '../register/register';
import Welcome from '../welcome/welcome';
import ResetPWD from '../register/resetpwd';
import RegisterLogin from '../register/registerlogin';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import SideStack from '../routes/sideStack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function homeStack({navigation}) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Register"
          component={Register}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ResetPWD"
          component={ResetPWD}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="RegisterLogin"
          component={RegisterLogin}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Welcome"
          component={Welcome}
          options={{
            title: 'Abulad',
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon
                name="comment"
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                title="Info"
                color="#000"
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default homeStack;
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import HomeStack from './src/components/routes/homeStack';
import SideStack from './src/components/routes/sideStack';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }
  render() {
    return <HomeStack />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

On executing the onPress method attached to the icon supposed to slide the drawer out, I get this error: 
[image: navigation error image]

Comment: in `homeStack` added `< SideStack/>` into `< NavigationContainer>....< NavigationContainer/>` befor `<Stack.Navigator>` like this `< NavigationContainer> < SideStack/> <Stack.Navigator>....<Stack.Navigator/>< NavigationContainer/>`

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: No, i still get an error

Comment: Error: another navigator is already registered for this container, you likely have multiple navigators under a single "navigatiocontainer" or "screen" make sure each navigator is under a separate screen container

Comment: Thats the error message I get, I am currently going through the [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/) docs on how to nest navigators

Comment: bug solved, the solution can be found here ![solution to error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481474/typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-gotten-when-using-navigation-opendrawer?noredirect=1#comment108758517_61481474)